# Java Set<String> in a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, set

I have this object:

```
Map<Long, Set<String>> resourcesByID = new HashMap<Long, Set<String>>();
```

and another:

```
Set<String> resources;
```

When I want to put more Set into the HashMap it will override the elements of the Set, that I put into previously. Why? And how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you give an example in which case this happens? How do you put the Sets into the HashMap?

Comment: You should post the code where you are using `resourcesById`.  It is likely you are just putting a new Set into the HashMap.  What you should do is check if the HashMap contains the Long you are about to use to insert.  If it does, you must get the Set from the map and add all elements from the insertion Set into it.  If it does not, just insert your insertion set.

Comment: It is likely you're not creating a new `Set` for each new key, and instead you are constantly pushing new elements into the same `resources` object then putting multiple references to said `resources` object for various keys into the hashmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `key` matches, it overrides the previous values, otherwise it won't override.

(or)

As Thomas commented, if your set is mutate and you are updating the same set, yes, then it may override.

Comment: Or worse, if you mutate the already inserted set from outside.

Comment: @user1732178: Keys are different, but you are updating same Set?

Comment: This was my problem: when i put the different elements into the HashMap, i use the same Set reference so it change all Sets in the HashMap. But now it works. Thanks a lot. That mutate comment helped ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming

```
Long id = 1234L;
Set<String> resources = ...;
```

If you want to add another mapping from a `Long` to a `Set` then

```
resourcesById.put(id, resources);
```

If you want to add `String`s to an existing mapping

```
resourcesById.get(id).addAll(resources);
```

And to make life simpler if you're not doing initialization correctly...

```
if (!resourcesById.containsKey(id)) {
    resourcesById.put(id, new HashSet<String>());
}
resourcesById.get(id).addAll(resources);
```

Answer (score 2):

- First reason you may be using same key for each set.
- Second reason if key is different than for each key (long) you might be using same Set
  using **resources** reference, you have to create the separate
  instance of Set for each key.